# C# finding number of digits of a number

Tags: c#, math, numbers

i want to count the digits behind the decimal point. 
The result i need is eg:

```
float n = 1,5674; // print There are 4 digits behind the decimal point.
```

I already got this. But I don't know how to make it work with decimals.

```
toTest = 1,5674
int i = 0;

do
{
    toTest = toTest / 10;
    i++;
}
while(Math.Abs(toTest) >= 1);
```

works perfectly fine, to find the lenght of a number >1. 
But i can't figure out how to count the decimal places.

I'm a trainee, so please don't butcher me if I overseen the right solution.

best regards

Comment: It's no problem that you're a trainee. It is a problem that you don't appear to have looked for a solution. I've found three duplicates with a single web search; please [edit] your question to show what you have tried if those don't help you.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see. I'll be more thoroughly next time. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *dividing*, *multiply* by `10`:

```
  double toTest = 1.5674;

  int i = 0;

  // note "toTest *= 10" instead of original "toTest = toTest / 10"
  for (; toTest - Math.Floor(toTest) != 0; toTest *= 10) 10;
    i += 1;

  Console.Write(i); // 4
```